# Replacing the NA values from one column with the values from another column using .fillna

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I tried to replace the NAs with the values under the Country Name and  with the values under the Primary Country of Risk and Country ISO2Code columns with the values from Primary Country of Risk and ISO2 Code of Primary Country of Risk, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
port_risk_coverage['Country Name'].fillna(port_risk_coverage['Primary Country of Risk'], inplace=True)
port_risk_coverage['Country ISO2Code'].fillna(port_risk_coverage['ISO2 Code of Primary Country of Risk'], inplace=True)
```

[NAs remain after running the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfxXK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your columns `"Country Name"` and `"Country ISO2Code"` do not actually contain `NaN` values to fill, but empty strings `""`. Try this snippet and first and then you can rerun your code and it should work:

```
import numpy as np

# Replace empty string for NaN throughout entire dataframe
port_risk_coverage = port_risk_coverage.replace("", np.nan)

port_risk_coverage['Country Name'].fillna(port_risk_coverage['Primary Country of Risk'], inplace=True)
port_risk_coverage['Country ISO2Code'].fillna(port_risk_coverage['Country ISO2Code'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Great! Glad it worked for you. Would you mind selecting this answer as correct so that others who have a similar question can find it?